# Find the residue of $e^{1/z}\sin(z)$ at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, residue-calculus

I am looking for the residues of $f(z)=e^{1/z}\sin(z)$ at its singular points.

Found that only $z=0$ is an essential singularity, where

$$a_{-1}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n-1)!(2n)!}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes: your computations are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both $e^z$ and $\sin z$ are entire functions, so $z=0$ is the only singularity of $f(z)=e^{1/z}\sin z$ and it is an essential singularity. We have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \text{Res}(f(z),z=0) &=& [z^{-1}]\left(\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{n! z^n}\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^m z^{2m+1}}{(2m+1)!}\right)\\&=&\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^m}{(2m+1)!(2m+2)!}.\end{eqnarray*}$$