# On a complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am trying to compute the following integral:

$$\oint_\gamma\exp(1/z)\cosh(z)dz$$

where $\gamma$ is the unit circle with the obvious orientation. I have tried to find a decent closed form for this but I seem to be running into difficulties.

What I have tried:  the first thing that comes to mind is to use the residue theorem, and since there is only one singularity (in $0$), this should theoretically be doable. However, since we have an essential singularity, it seems quite nontrivial to me how to actually compute the residue. What I mean by this is: obviously I can write (on $\gamma$)

$$\exp(1/z)\cosh(z)=\left(\sum\frac{1}{n!z^n} \right)\left(\sum \frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}\right)=
\sum_{n+m=0}^\infty\frac{z^{2m-n}}{(2m)!n!}$$

so that the residue in $0$ is generated by those factors in which $2m-n=1$ and so
$\text{Res}(f,0)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2m)!(2m+1)!}$ but this is far from being a decent closed form for the residue.

I have lookd around on this site and I found a few similar integral but they where all solved by making use of simmetries that my integral seems to lack

Comment: Welcome to MSE. That's a nice first question!

Comment: Similar problem here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1325016/42969. My guess would be that there is no “nicer” representation.

Comment: We get a sum of two Bessel functions, because
$$e^{z + 1/z} = \sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} I_n(2) z^n, \quad
e^{-z + 1/z} = \sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} (-1)^n J_n(2) z^n.$$