# residue of $f(z) = \frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{\sin(z)}$ at point $0$.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I have absolutely no idea how to do this. It was presented as a challenging complex analysis question. The original exercise was to calculate the residue of $f(z) = \frac{\sin(z)}{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}$ at point $0$. Which is pretty easy, then, they asked us as a challenging exercise, to calculate the residue of the reciprocal of $f(z)$. We spend a good 20 minutes but with absolutely no result.

Comment: Inverse? $f(2\pi)=f(\pi)=0$ . It is not injective. Do you mean $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ ?

Comment: Yep, sorry guys I misused the word "inversed". I meant reciprocal as Anne corrected me :).

Comment: the Mathematica code `Residue[Sin[z]/Exp[1/z], {z, 0}]` shows:

Residues are not defined at branch points.

Comment: @138Aspen "The residue of the residue of $f(z) = \frac{\sin(z)}{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}$ at point $0$ is pretty easy", and $0$ is neither a branch point of $f$ nor of $1/f$.

Comment: $e^z$ has an essential singularity at $z=\infty$ with the known consequence, the the function assumes all values on $\mathbb C$ except for two $(0,\infty)$ in any neigbourhood of $z=\infty$. Imagine in the geometry of the Riemann sphere. The same is true for $e^{\frac{1}{z}}$ at $z=0$, Riemann sphere, poles exchanged. Unit factors don't play a role (rotations), a multiplication by $\sin z ,  z$ at $z=0$ cannot flatten the monster. The coefficient of $z^{-1}$ of the series $z*/(z^n n!)$ is trivial, of course. Essential singularity - infinitely many integer powers - is not a branch point.

Comment: You say the residue of $e^{-1/z}\sin z$ is "pretty easy", but as far as I can see the value is expressed as an infinte sum. Or there is a closed form that I miss ?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I thought Henri only meant that it is "pretty easy" to express the value as (the opposite of) [this infinite sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1325016).

Comment: @AnneBauval OK. You are very efficient in finding related posts. For me it would take ages.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Found [using Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%5Cinfty%5Cfrac%7Bz%5En%7D%7B(2n%2B1)!(2n%2B2)!%7D%24&p=1) with "AND site:math.stackexchange.com, OR content:$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{(2n+1)!(2n+2)!}$"

Comment: Henri, under which form precisely was the result requested in your "challenging exercise"? I mean: weren't you already aware of Andy's (partial) solution below? Did your challenging asker tell you there was a more complete one?

Comment: Henri, please edit your post to add some "context" (like the details of your solution for the first "pretty easy" part, and of your fruitless attempts for the second "hard" part), so that it can be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a different approach, I think the sum of all the residues of $f(z)$ should equal $0$.

For all the residues at points others than $z=0$, [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=residues%20of%20e%5E%281%2Fz%29%2Fsin%28z%29) states the residues are

$$ \mathrm{Res}_{z=2n\pi}\left[\dfrac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{\sin(z)}\right] = e^{\frac{1}{2n\pi}}$$
$$ \mathrm{Res}_{z=(2n+1)\pi}\left[\dfrac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{\sin(z)}\right] = -e^{\frac{1}{(2n+1)\pi}}$$

So, I think

$$\begin{align*}  \mathrm{Res}_{z=0}\left[\dfrac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{\sin(z)}\right] &= 0 - \sum_{n=-\infty, n\ne0}^\infty (-1)^n e^{\frac{1}{n\pi}} \\
\\
&= 0 - 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \cosh\left({\frac{1}{n\pi}}\right) \\
\\
&= 2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left[ \cosh\left({\frac{1}{(2k-1)\pi}}\right)-\cosh\left({\frac{1}{2k\pi}}\right) \right]\\
\\
&\approx 0.0841464 \\
\end{align*}$$

That numerical result comes from [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%20n%3D1%20to%20infinity%202%28%5Ccosh%5Cleft%28%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%282n-1%29%5Cpi%7D%7D%5Cright%29-%5Ccosh%5Cleft%28%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%282n%29%5Cpi%7D%7D%5Cright%29%29)

Someone with a stronger background than me should really check if this is legitimate to do.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an essential singularity, as @Roland_F suggests, then the only technique I know of to find the residue is to find the $b_1$ coefficient of the $\dfrac{b_1}{z}$ term of the Laurent series of $f(z)$.

Writing
$$\begin{align*}f(z) &= \dfrac{e^\frac{1}{z}}{\sin(z)} = \dfrac{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n!}\dfrac{1}{z^n}}{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}z^{2k+1}}\\
\end{align*}$$
You can perform just the steps necessary of the polynomial division of the series for $\sin(z)$ into each of the even powered terms in the numerator (the odd powers don't contribute) to get the contributions to the $b_1$ coefficient.

The polynomial division is pretty tedious.  Here are the first few contributions to the $b_1$ coefficient:

$$\begin{align*}b_1 &= 1 \\
&+ -\dfrac{1}{2!}\left[\left(-\dfrac{1}{3!}\right)\right]\\
&+ -\dfrac{1}{4!}\left[\left(\dfrac{1}{5!}\right) -\left(-\dfrac{1}{3!}\right)^2\right]\\
&+ -\dfrac{1}{6!}\left[\left(-\dfrac{1}{7!}\right) -2\left(\dfrac{1}{5!}\right)\left(-\dfrac{1}{3!}\right)+\left(-\dfrac{1}{3!}\right)^3\right]\\
&+ -\dfrac{1}{8!}\left[\left(\dfrac{1}{9!}\right) -2\left(-\dfrac{1}{7!}\right)\left(-\dfrac{1}{3!}\right)+\left(\dfrac{1}{5!}\right)\left(-\dfrac{1}{3!}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{1}{5!}\right)^2-\left(-\dfrac{1}{3!}\right)^4\right]\\
&+ \dots\\
\end{align*}$$

All of the even factorial terms come from the series in the numerator.  All of the odd factorial terms come from the series for $\sin(z)$.

**Update**

Given the observation that the odd powers in the numerator of $f(z)$ don't contribute to the residue at $z=0$, the following function should have the same residue as $f(z)$:

$$\begin{align*}g(z) &= \dfrac{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{1}{(2n)!}\dfrac{1}{z^{2n}}}{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}z^{2k+1}} = \dfrac{\cosh\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)}{\sin(z)} = \dfrac{\cos\left(\frac{i}{z}\right)}{\sin(z)}\\
\end{align*}$$

I doubt that will help, but it was worth mentioning.

Comment: Well, this is the same as [@C.Dubussy's (obvious and now self-deleted) answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4839787). I began the same first calculations, and probably so did the OP, but that does not tell us the wanted result. I am beginning to doubt it is feasible.

Comment: @AnneBauval FWIW, from page 176 of "Complex Variables and Applications, Fifth Edition" R.Churchill, J. Brown: "The basic method for finding the residue of a function at an isolated singular point $z_0$ is that of appealing directly to the appropriate Laurent series and noting the coefficient of $1/(z-z_0)$.  When $z_0$ is an essential singular point, we offer no other method."

Comment: Thank you for this quote. It does not completely exclude the possibility that there exists "another method" and/or a more explicit result, at least for this special case. But it seems doubtful indeed.

Comment: Right.  There may be a special case here or maybe another way to develop a Laurent series, but I have no ideas for that.